# Mapping element in configuration specifies no attributes Error occurred when i try to run my project in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Error occurred when i try to run my project in Hibernate.The error is as follows.

> Mapping element in configuration specifies no attributes

Can anyone help me in clearing this error

Comment: http://www.mohanarun.com/mapping-element-in-configuration-specifies-no-attributes-error-in-hibernate/  seems to indicate that you need to look at your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and remove any empty mapping elements (as in `<mapping/>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error seems to typically be caused, literally, by an empty `mapping` element in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

To fix this, open the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, and remove any `mapping` element that is empty, that is, any element that looks like `<mapping />`.

Source: http://www.mohanarun.com/mapping-element-in-configuration-specifies-no-attributes-error-in-hibernate/